# Вывод JSON в Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Подскажите, как можно передать параметр в функцию с JSON данными, после чего вывести JSON с полученным параметром?

```
var myfunc = function(param){
 var json = {
   "result":"ok",
   "parametr" : param
   };
document.write(json);
} ;

If(x > y)
{myfunc(1);} 
else
{myfunc(0);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода json как текста есть функция [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
var myfunc = function(param){
 var user = {
   "result":"ok",
   "parametr" : param
   };
document.write(JSON.stringify(user));
} ;
var x = y = 0;
if(x > y)
{myfunc(1);} 
else
{myfunc(0);}
```

Comment: Спасибо, пример рабочий. Ваш совет помог мне упростить код!